# How to access the directories outside the subdomain folder

Tags: php, apache, subdomain, document-root

How do I access a folder outside my subdomain folder.

For example, my domain is `localhost` and I have a subdomain `m.localhost`. And their folders are:

```
Server Root:
    /cdn/
    /contents/
    /mobile/
    .htaccess
```

And the folder `/mobile/` is the root directory of my `m.localhost`. From the `m.localhost`, how do I access the `/contents/` directory and it's contents using PHP?

`$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` only selects the subdomain directory root.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.

```
realpath(dirname(__FILE__).'/../../../contents/nav/quicklinks.txt');
```

Comment: Well, I was trying to get a file's content on the `/contents/` folder and store it as a variable. I wanted to achieve: `$quicklinks = file_get_contents(realpath(dirname(__FILE__).'/../contents/nav/quicklinks.txt'));` but I got this error: `Warning: file_get_contents(): Filename cannot be empty in C:\XAMPP\htdocs\mobile\cdn\php\nav.php on line 5`. How to fix?

Comment: @KevinHandogTresuelo Since your calling the script from a sub directory of mobile folder its not working. I have updated my answer.

Comment: @KevinHandogTresuelo Your welcome. Don't forget to +1 if it was helpful.

Comment: is there a way that the `/../../../contents/nav/quicklinks.txt` be an absolute url? Like it would be just `/contents/nav/quicklinks.txt`?